# New className call not working in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to develop an php website using `phpMyEdit` , this is the [link](http://www.phpmyedit.org/) for the project. It was working until recently.

I updated my `php` to `php7.0` then it stopped working. This is the issue.

```
// Now important call to phpMyEdit
require_once 'extensions/phpMyEdit-mce-cal.class.php';
new phpMyEdit_mce_cal($opts);
```

I have included the class file `phpMyEdit-mce-cal.class.php` till there it works. The `new phpMyEdit_mce_cal($opts)` doesnt work.

Is there some changes in the lastest version of `php7.0` ?

Comment: maybe phpMyEdit is not optimized for PHP7 - its hard to find on their website what they do and do not support...

Comment: PHP 7 Should not break the functionality. What errors do you see? Check [Adminer](https://www.adminer.org/). It's a similar project and it works on PHP7 for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with that extension is that is trying to use MySQL and not MySQLi...

MySQL in PHP7.x is removed, so you will have to use MySQLi to make it work... there are lot of MySQL commands in `phpMyEdit.class.php`.

[Here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysql.php) you can see oficial information about MySQL in PHP webpage.